# multicol: increase space between columns

Tags: spacing, multicol

How to increase the space between two columns in a `multicol`?

[image: increase space between columns]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlength\columnsep{30pt}`